# Verify all rows of Dataframe1 are present in Dataframe2

Tags: r

Example:
**dataframe1** has following rows and columns.

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| A       | B       | C       | D       | E       |
| P       | Q       | R       | S       | T       |
| J       | K       | L       | M       | N       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**dataframe2** has following rows and columns.

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| B       | D       | E       | M       | N       |
| Q       | S       | T       | R       | A       |
| M       | Q       | R       | A       | T       |
| A       | B       | C       | D       | E       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

What I want to do is first iterate through dataframe1 and check if the first row of **dataframe1** is present in **dataframe2**. Here in this example, first row of **dataframe1** is present in forth row of **dataframe2**. In the same way I want to check if all the rows of **dataframe1** are present in **dataframe2**. I could achieve this with multiple **for** loops. But, I would like to do it in a simpler and faster way.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  Perhaps `all(do.call(paste, df1) %in% do.call(paste, df2))`

Comment: @akrun I am new to SO, so, didn't know I had to accept the solution. Accepted it.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I posted two possible solutions.  It may be better to show the expected output.  Also, does the order of values in the rows matter?

Comment: @akrun Both the data frames have columns in the same order - Col1, Col2, Col3 and so on.

Comment: I meant in the example, the first row is `A B C D E` and it is equal to the 4th row in `df2`.   If the row is `B C D A E`, would you consider it as equal?

Comment: No. I want them in the same order i.e. A B C D E.

Comment: In that case, the solution I posted should work.  Can you test it?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. But, I realized this is not I want. Dataframe1 and Dataframe2, do not have exact data. In this example - in Dataframe1, the data in first column is "Indian Inc." whereas in Dataframe2, it is "India". This is true across multiple columns. I want a similar match - something based on agrepl. I'll post this as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `paste` the rows in each dataset (`do.call(paste,...)`) and compare them using `%in%.  The output will be a logical vector.  If`all`the values from the`paste` output in 'df1' are present in 'df2', it will give 'TRUE' or else 'FALSE

```
 all(do.call(paste, df1) %in% do.call(paste, df2))
```

Another option is using `anti_join` from `dplyr'.  If all the rows in 'df1' are found in 'df2', the output will be '0' row.

```
library(dplyr)
nrow(anti_join(df1, df2))==0
```

Answer (score 0):

Base package. TRUE in case all are present, FALSE otherwise:

```
nrow(unique(merge(df1, df2))) == nrow(unique(df1))
```